# Language changing only after page refresh

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual, jhtml

I have multilingual (fa/en) Joomla 3.6.2 site using Protostar template. The problem is when I click on the fa - (persian flag) or UK flag, the lang and dir tag does not change, but when I hit the refresh button they change to correct value. Also the site does not load correct CSS.

Comment: Do you enable the joomla cache or having any cache extension installed?

Comment: no i make this web from scratch with plain joomla 3.6.4 and the cache is disabled!

Comment: Can you share the website url?

Comment: no,unfortunately .i'm working on localhost

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with Joomla 3.6.5. The problem may have been already there with 3.6.4.

I disabled the cache in the system configuration and I disabled the cache plugin. So far I cannot observe a change: After about 2 page reloads, the website switches from German (set as default) to English.

Answer (score 0):

i rolled back joomla version from 3.6.3 to 3.3.3 and the problem solved !

Comment: hi - keep in mind that this can be considered as a viable solution though - as using older Joomla versions, especially outdated and vulnerable ones is not a good idea. So although it gave you a quick solution, this must be a temporary one and for your localhost site only to give you time to update properly the site.

Comment: thank u FFrewin do you have any Idea?

Comment: You have to re-try to update (on a test site) to achieve a workable 3.6.4 site and try to find out what is the cause of your issues - if those persist.